# how to set the corner radius of the cells on UITableViewStyleGrouped?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, cornerradius

I have a tableview, which has many sections. each section has just one cell. I wonder if I can set the cell's corner radius to what I wanted. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: you can set the background image. just make an image looks like corner radius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITableViewCell.layer is kind of class CALayer and CALayer class have a property called cornerRadius. so you set the cell's corner radius as fallows:

```
[cell.layer setCornerRadius:3.0];
```

Comment: I can't seem to make this work - I'm trying to set the corner radius on the cell at Row 0 of Section 0 (i.e. the top cell). However, it never changes (nor does it appear to have a corner radius set at all). Any thoughts on what I might be missing?